# Another Input String is not in its correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I did search this before posting here, but couldn't find the answer.

```
try
        {
            int qty, price, tot;

            qty = Convert.ToInt32(txtQty.Text);
            price = Convert.ToInt32(txtPrice.Text);

            if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value == "0")
            {
                price = 10;
                tot = Convert.ToInt32(qty * price);
                txtPrice.Text = tot.ToString();
            }
            if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
            {
                price = 20;
                tot = Convert.ToInt32(qty * price);
                txtPrice.Text = tot.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            lblItemMessage.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

The message it keeps on giving me is "Input String is not in its correct format." It worked out fine when I was did it before without the if statement but now it is just giving this message. Right now it isn't giving any error message but it isn't adding to the database as well.

I have tried Int32.TryParse() but it gives me the same error. The calculated price suppose to show in the txtPrice.Text. the Qty text box is in number text mode.

I would appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: What's the input? On which line does it fail?

Comment: `Int32.TryParse() but it gives me the same error.` There is no possibility for this; could you please include the code with `Int32.TryParse()`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it will help, but since `qty` and `price` are already in int format, it's useless to convert them to int again.
So I'd just write:

> tot = qty * price;

Also, you are converting in both `if` `tot` to string, so you can put it at the end of the second if to have better readability. Like this:

> ```
>         if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value == "0")
>         {
>             price = 10;
>             tot = qty * price;
>         }
>         else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
>         {
>             price = 20;
>             tot = qty * price;
>         }
>         txtPrice.Text = tot.ToString();
> ```

Comment: i think it would be better if use `else if` as the second `IF`

Comment: @Mark yes you're right, didn't pay attention to that detail :)

Answer (score 1):

I have Few suggestions for you:

If you are using [`Int32.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) it will never throws FormatException since TryParse method does not throw an exception if the conversion fails. It eliminates the need to use exception handling to test for a FormatException in the event that s is invalid and cannot be successfully parsed.

You have declared `qty, price, tot` as integers so you need not to convert it again using `Convert.ToInt32()` to assign it to `tot`.

Use Proper naming Conventions, it will help you to improve readability and understand-ability.

Let me rewrite the snippet as follows:

```
int itemQuantity, itemPrice, itemTotal;

if (Int32.TryParse(txtQty.Text, out itemQuantity) && Int32.TryParse(txtitemPrice.Text, out itemPrice))
{
    if (ddlOption.SelectedItem.Value == "0")
    {
       itemTotal=itemQuantity * itemPrice + 10;
       txtPrice.Text=itemTotal.ToString();
    }
    else if (ddlOption.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
    {
       itemTotal=itemQuantity * itemPrice + 20;
       txtPrice.Text=itemTotal.ToString();
    }
}
```